# Pointer to return value of vector iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a vector of structs e.g

```
struct IDS{
   string name;
   int age;
   IDS(string name, int age){
    this->name = name;
    this ->age = age;
   }
}

vector<IDS> myVector;
```

I am filling this vector with structs , and later on i want find a struct with specific value and save pointer to it. I tried using

```
IDS *tmp;

auto it = find_if (temp->myVector.begin(), temp->myVector.end(), [&](const IDS &y) { 
    return y.age == age; 
});

if ( it != temp -> myVector.begin() ){
    tmp =it
}
```

the vector is inside a linked list. This throws this error

> cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator
>
> > ' to 'IDS*' in assignment|

How can i fix this error , and how can i store iterator pointer ?

Comment: Misleading indentation. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`it` is an iterator, not a pointer. You can use `tmp = &(*it);` to convert the iterator to a pointer.

Alternatively you could make `tmp` a `std::vector<IDS>::iterator`.

Comment: How could i store copy of that , not by reference?

Comment: @user3706129 `IDS tmp; tmp = *it;` makes a copy of the `IDS` that `it` points to.